# Sync iPhone applications in iTunes

Tags: itunes

Suppose I have one the one hand one iTunes library on a PC used to sync Outlook contacts and calendar plus on the other hand one iTunes library on a Mac that syncs music, podcasts, apps, ringtones, etc. Both libraries are based on iTunes 9.0.2.

It turns out that the iTunes library on the PC always tries to sync apps and ringtones as well. Unfortunately, this boils down to deleting apps and ringtones from the iPhone because the apps are not part of the iTunes library on the PC. After unchecking the checkbox to sync apps and ringtones and plugging the iPhone into the Mac the checkbox is also unchecked on the Mac.

It seems as if the settings for syncing apps and ringtones are stored on the iPhone rather than in the particular iTunes library. Whenever syncing apps and ringtones is active on one machine it is also active on the other and vice versa.

How can I make the PC ignore apps and ringtones and **only** sync contacts and calendar?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=2137) might do the trick.  The problem is that iTunes wants you to sync with only one computer (or manually).  This twiddles the bits in iTunes to convince the iPod/iPhone that the two computers have the same library.

It isn't clear if you need to have the same files on both systems, but it does let you automatically sync to two different computers.

Comment: I confirm that it works and I have done this already and successfully managed to make the iPhone sync with iTunes libraries on two different computers. But that does unfortunately not answer my question. I don't want to share content on both libraries. 

All I want is to make the PC-based library sync calendar and contacts and keep its hands off my apps.

Comment: My guess is that iPhone/iTunes does this so you don't lose apps/ringtones you purchase on the phone.  I don't know of a way around this.